# security how to freeze DOM Elements it's that remotely possible? [cheating with grades]

Tags: javascript, html, security

Recently a client (school) ask to build an app for show grades to their students, so is quite easy show grades over html table reading the database etc.

But one security issue is bother me, Kids are quite smart and sometimes they found the way to show different grades to their parent, grades that they didn't deserve, So from that suppose I think is quite easy doing something like:

```
$("table tr td").each(function(index, item){ $(item).text("A++") });
```

And `voila` you change the browser screen show your parents and your are free to go with you girlfriend that easy.

With google console or firefox firebug you can modify the html to appear you got different grades, They know at the end they will face their destiny against REAL grades. But in meanwhile buy time lol.

So basically I came with the idea to render the grade into an Image but that is NOT cool from design perspective, maintainability, accessibility, etc.

I think this is a question to resolve from the server but just for a chance (remote chance) it's a way to froze DOM element and denied any kind of action over them?, or Do you have a great idea to solve this problem out of the box?

thanks in advance..

Comment: They can always "Save page as...", then edit. You're better off requiring the parents to log in themselves. Alternatively, you could use PDF, Flash, images, or something less malleable. Taking a "code approach" to a social problem is difficult.

Comment: Well good point about "Save page as"

Comment: The kids who know Firebug are generally getting pretty decent grades, if my experience is any indication.

Comment: Parents who believe everything their kid says are beyond naive.

Comment: no matter what you do anyone can open any page or image in an editor... personally, i don't think this is your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple: don't trust kids to show their parents anything. All it takes is one smart kid to reproduce your HTML and show perfect grades, then share the link with everyone and then even the class idiot can show straight As to their parents.

Instead, as Wesley Murch says, you should give the parents the ability to log in, not their kids. The parents can then see their child's progress without interference.

Comment: Yes I think will have to be in this way... delegate the grade control to the parents.

Answer (score 1):

Kolink's answer is good. For the practical coding answer, you will always be able to manipulate DOM, so, though not as friendly, you could do the image approach. There are only so many grades and so only so many images, so it isn't really that resource intensive.

You will want to, however, name the images unrecognizably, as otherwise the kid could just change the image name, and we're back to where we started.

Another possible idea is to look into HTML 5 Canvases. You can do a lot in one that people can't easily directly edit.

Comment: Canvas is a good idea in theory, but really `ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500); ctx.fillText("A++",32,32);` (or similar) can easily replace their contents - a parent who doesn't know what it should look like won't know the difference.